# EF query performance issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

If i only pass `createdFromDate` to the lambda below, my query finished in about 300ms. But if i pass the `id` parameter, I end up in about 20-30 seconds. Is there any way to improve the query when passing the `id` variable?

```
List<MYENTITY> list= ctx.MYENTITY.Where(s => 
      (string.IsNullOrEmpty(createdFrom) || s.CREATE_DATE >= createdFrom) && 
      (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || s.ANOTHER_ENTITY.FirstOrDefault().ID == id)
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this isn't the fault of EF. What I would do is to capture the query being generated by EF, paste it into SSMS and look at the query plan. My guess is that a table or index scan is being done, because an index is missing. Or, an index exists but is not being used, possibly because one or more columns should be included in the index.

Comment: Ok, is there an easy way to find out the sql query which is being generated?

Comment: There are two ways to do it. You can use Profiler to see what is being sent to the target SQL Server. Or, EF provides a way to capture the SQL query, but I can't recall, at the moment, how to do it.

Comment: If you are using sql express you won't have the Profiler, either way it's worth getting hold of a copy of http://www.linqpad.net/ which helps to write L2E queries (and allows you to view the sql) or you could use http://www.sqltolinq.com/ if you want to go the other way around and convert sql to L2E

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing to try:

```
List<MYENTITY> list = ctx.MYENTITY.Where(s => 
  string.IsNullOrEmpty(createdFrom) || s.CREATE_DATE >= createdFrom)
  .ToList()
  .Where(s2 => string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || s2.ANOTHER_ENTITY.FirstOrDefault().ID == id)
  .ToList();
```

This is not a solution, but if it speeds things up then I'd suggest looking at your code, if the speed stays the same, I'd suggest looking at your database structure.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to cache the list and make use of the cached version instead?

Comment: well, by `ToList()`ing the results, they are becoming effectively cached (i.e. will be available as long as the list stays in scope). Depending on your usage, you may also have to keep the context in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not get the evaluated ID of:

```
s.ANOTHER_ENTITY.FirstOrDefault().ID
```

i.e. int? anotherEntityId = s.ANOTHER_ENTITY.FirstOrDefault().ID;

And use that in place of the above line of code.

As I think including it in the where clause will in effect quite possibly (depending on the ef query used to obtain this entity) cause the final sql query to be one hell of a mess.

At least I think it's worth testing.

That is you could substitute the anotherEntityId to some known value and test, if it is slow then it is the evaluation of

```
s.ANOTHER_ENTITY.FirstOrDefault().ID
```

that is the real problem.